# Having trouble Encoding hebrew text in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (console application) c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to make a new excel file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and no matter what im doing im getting xlsx file filld with gibberish.. 
more info: 
i populates datatable from text file
and then use the datatable to fill the execl sheet

```
OfficeExcel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
                excelWorkSheet.Name = "789";
            for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
                    byte[] latinBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255").GetBytes(table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString());
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = hebrewEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);
                }
            }
        }
        excelWorkBook.SaveAs(path + ExcelfileName + ".xlsx", OfficeExcel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
                             misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, OfficeExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                             misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        excelWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        excelApp.Quit();
```

i already tried Various typs of Encodings and obviously I'm doing something wrong.

[here is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dssk.png)

Comment: Are you sure the text file is encoded using windows-1255 and not cp-862?

Comment: yes, since im making the text file this way`StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"));`

Comment: install notepad++ open the text file and make sure
that ENCODING is checked with UTF8 instead of ANSII